# Why doesn't a:active property work in Asp.net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, anchor

I have a list menu in Asp.net MVC Razor engine Masterpage. While trying some CSS on the menu, i see that the `a:active` property doesn't work as it should. I have cross check for reference on w3schools but still can't figure it out.

Following is the HTML on master page :-

```
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="/Store/Electronics">Electronics</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Store/Computers">Computers</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Store/Clothings">Clothing And Accressories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Store/Office">Office</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Store/Sports">Sports</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS code :-

```
.nav ul li a:link { text-decoration:none; color:#3C7777; font-weight:bold; }
.nav ul li a:visited { text-decoration:none; color:#3C7777; } 
.nav ul li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #B5B5B5; }
.nav ul li a:active { text-decoration:none; color:#B5B5B5; }
```

Question :- The selected link is not show in the correct color, #B5B5B5, Why ??

Comment: This all looks correct - and has nothing to do with MVC. Check the rendered HTML and CSS with Firebug.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing :active with :focus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure you're not missing something - The :active pseudo-class only applies while you are clicking the link, and holding down the mouse button. It will not work after a page reload. (Just making sure, as it's a common mistake to make)

Comment: ohh k....absolutely correct....i had this feeling that how can the color be preserved when i am moving to another page....but was lazy and thinking that somehow CSS should do the magic :-P ....

Comment: No harm done - If you want to mark the active link, you'll have to assign it a class, say "active" on pageload. You could, for instance, evaluate the current querystring to determine which page the user is on and mark up the correct link. Best of luck!